# Is there any possibility to port OrientDB to .NET (C#)

Tags: c#, port, ikvm, orientdb

By ikvm or any other tool, is it possible to port OrientDb to .NET(C#) ? I asked this because they said this is so tiny database :)
Or converting low level java library  to c# is not safe?

Yes someone can say, there is a REST api and we can use it by C# easily. But integrated usage is more effective. For example I could not install OrientDB server to windows. It stole 4 hours of my life! And no chance for me

Surely i think OrientDb is ok for production (web application)

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

There is already Blueprints.NET and Pipes.NET, so you could use it and just port the OrientDB persistency layer to .NET. Happy forking ;)

Comment: I downloaded Bluprints.Net and it seems a socialgraph demo does not work. This subject highly related with this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559972/db4o-activation-depth-faq-best-practise-for-web-application/5565679. I dont have free time, My brain will blow up :( Neo4J, OrientDB, Redis, Bluprints, Gremlin, MongoDB. I think i will use provider pattern and after 4 months i will use BluprintsGremlinGraphProvider. But for now I need Social Graph and Notification! What do you suppose ? Thx.

Comment: These products (Blueprints.Net and Pipes.net) are not ready for development.. I suspended my researches on them.

Comment: OrientDB is now nearing 1.0 (rc2 expected tomorrow) and passing all Tinkerpop unit tests.